# Display names under profile pics Firebase Web Realtime-Database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

[User specific info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s9k7.png)[Profile pic display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Srcy.jpg)I fixed a ton of bugs I had before.
Goal: Dynamically display all signed up users with their names displayed under their profile pic.
What it does now: Dynamically displays all users(when you click it shows specific user info) and profile pics in seperate divs.
Image:Dynamic images displayed
Snippet:

```js
const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
const usersRef = dbRef.child('userInfo');
const userListUI = document.getElementById("userList");
usersRef.on("child_added", snap => {
  let user = snap.val();
  let $h3 = document.createElement("h3");
  $h3.innerHTML = user.name;
  $h3.setAttribute("child-key", snap.key);
  $h3.addEventListener("click", userClicked)
  userListUI.append($h3);
});

function userClicked(e) {
  var userID = e.target.getAttribute("child-key");
  const userRef = dbRef.child('userInfo/' + userID);
  const userDetailUI = document.getElementById("userDetail");
  userDetailUI.innerHTML = ""
  userRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var $p = document.createElement("p");
    $p.innerHTML = snap.key + " - " + snap.val()
    userDetailUI.append($p);
  });
}

var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
$('#List').find('tbody').html('');

var i = 0;
storageRef.child('users').listAll().then(function(result) {
  result.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {
    i++;
    displayImage(i, imageRef);
  });
});

function displayImage(row, images) {
  images.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    // console.log(url);
    let new_html = '';
    // new_html += '<tr>';
    new_html += '<td>';
    // new_html += '</td>';
    // new_html += '<td>';
    new_html += '<img src= "' + url + '">';
    new_html += '</td>';
    // new_html += '</tr>';
    new_html += row;
    $('#List').find('tbody').append(new_html);
  });
}
```

```html
<table id="List">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

<ul id="userList"></ul>
<div id="userDetail">
  <p>
    <strong class="detailName"></strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

What I've done to try to fix:Googling, playing around with the display image function (tried moving the $('#List').find('tbody').append(new_html); below the 2nd to last });) add something to the new_html to display names but the images.getDownloadURL messes the other stuff I tried because if I add another function after or before it, I'll get an error because the images are stored in storage and the user info is in realtime database. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var userData = docRef.collection("userInfo");
 usersRef.on("child_added", snap => {
     let user = snap.val();
     let $ul = document.createElement("ul");
     $ul.innerHTML = user.name;
     $ul.setAttribute("child-key", snap.key);
     $ul.addEventListener("click", userClicked) 
     userListUI.append($ul);
 });
 function userClicked(e) {
   var userID = e.target.getAttribute("child-key");
   const imageRef = storageRef.child('users/' + userID);
   const userRef = dbRef.child('userInfo/' + userID);
   // window.location = 'profileview.html';
   const userDetailUI = document.getElementById("userDetail");
   userDetailUI.innerHTML = "";
   userRef.on("child_added", snap => {
       var $ul = document.createElement("ul");
       $ul.innerHTML = snap.key + " - " + snap.val() 
       userDetailUI.append($ul);
   });
 }
```

Comment: I asked the question like a month ago

Comment: And that has to do with what I tell you. Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem, thanks.